# Run queries on remote PostgreSQL from LibreOffice Calc

Tags: vba, postgresql, remote-access, libreoffice-calc

My goal is to run simple queries from LibreOffice Calc and get the results from a remote PostgreSQL database.

I tried to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834998/libreoffice-calc-execute-a-postgresql-function) answer but I get an error.

Here is what I have:

```
Sub GetQuery
   Dim oParms(1) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue 
   Dim oStatement As Object
   Dim oResult As Object
   Dim oConnection As Object

   oParms(0).Name = "user" 
   oParms(0).Value = "serveruser" 
   oParms(1).Name = "password" 
   oParms(1).Value = "serverpwd" 
   oManager = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.sdbc.DriverManager")
   sURL = "dbname=mydatabase hostaddr=X.X.X.X port=5432 user=postgresuser password=postgrespwd"
   oConnection = oManager.getConnectionWithInfo(sURL, oParms())

   oStatement = oConnection.createStatement()
   oResult = oStatement.executeQuery("select count(*) from mytable")

   MsgBox "Result: " & oResult
   oStatement.close()
End Sub
```

When I try to run this I get "Object variable not set" on line `oStatement = oConnection.createStatement()`.

As you can see I have very limited experience on remote database connection.